# How to download permanently moved web page content using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, http-headers

My problem is how to download moved web pages [(Error code 301)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193681(v=vs.118)). The code bellow throw exception:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var t = httpClient.GetAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

My question is to recommend best method for above task. Should I use the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.

Comment: If the page has been moved or deleted, then you are not going to be able to get the content you want using the given url., plus if you are going to use `async`, you should be doing, `var t = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");` You also should post the exception message you are getting.

Comment: How about read some kind of information about redirection from web page header?

Comment: Check http status code and if its 301 then check "Location" response header which will contain new location (url). Use this new location and fire up another download request. If its just downloading page then Httpclient or Webclient either one is good.

Comment: What exception does this throw? I just ran this code myself and did _not_ get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page that has been moved has a new URL it will be returned in the `Location` header.
The response on it's own will not cause an exception, but it is common to call `.EnsureSuccessSatusCode()` which *will* throw an exception. You could try something live this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");

// if you call response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode here it will throw an exception

if (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Moved || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
    var location = response.Headers.Location;
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(location);
}
```